# Execute the Signout code without being redirected on sp page

Tags: 2010

I need to execute the the code under "/_layouts/Signout.aspx" on my Sharepoint page without any redirection and remaining on same page .Can i use the page viewer webpart and call the code ? or is there any other way ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your best option is a tiny bit of jQuery code to asynchronously call the SignOut page...

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/_layouts/SignOut.aspx"
}).done(function() {
  alert('user signed out!');
});
```

(Omit the `.done()` bit if you don't need it.)

Comment: Clever idea ! +1!

Comment: Thanks this is good way of doing.Anyways i added a page viewer webpart and set the URL to "layouts/Signout" and then set the height width of page viewer to 1 px.This too worked for me . .